# Category lists page foreach Paging

Tags: pagination, taxonomy, php

I use the following code shows the classification of the article with a list of all the category list on the page template, but such a page will be displayed all categories. I hope one page displays only six categories. Other classified pagination show the way through!

[image]

As shown, I would like to achieve this effect.
Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'series';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
foreach ($terms as $cat) {
$catid = $cat->term_id;
$args = array(
'showposts' => 10, 
'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'terms' => $catid ) )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
<ul>
<li><h2><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $cat ); ?>" ><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></h2>
<ul>
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```